# Processing scale() shape() and shapeMode() don't fit image to screen corners. Alternative?

Tags: scale, processing, shapes

I'm quite new to processing, but I wanted to make a web page with an interactive map and this seemed like the only/easier way to do it.

I learned a bit and it's really cool, but there seems to be some problem with the scale() and shape() function when drawing images (at least SVG images).

I tried the following code, either by commenting the `worldMap.scale(xScale, yScale);` line on or off. In fact I tried many more stuff, but it's just impossible to get the map correctly. Even if you get the scale correctly, part of Alaska doesn't show up.

```
PShape worldMap;
float xScale;
float yScale;

void setup() {
  size(900, 500);
  worldMap = loadShape("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/BlankMap-World6-Equirectangular.svg");
  xScale = width / worldMap.width;
  yScale = height / worldMap.height;
  //worldMap.scale(xScale, yScale);
  smooth(); // Improves the drawing quality of the SVG
  noLoop();
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  translate(0, 0);
  // Draw the full map
  shapeMode(CORNERS);
  shape(worldMap, 0, 0, 900, 500);
  //saveFrame("map output.png");
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've lost hours with this "small" problem.
From some posts I read in SO searching for a solution, it seems to indicate there is some problem with the scale() function in Processing, but I couldn't manage to get the answer to my problem from them.

Answer (score 1):

After some checking in Processing and the SVG source, it looks like this SVG is a bit of a liar. It has a viewbox with different dimensions from its 'height' and 'width' attributes, which are the attributes that Processing looks at for determining shape .width and .height...

As it turns out, the height and width are set to 432 and 855, respectively, but the REAL dimensions are actually 1396 and 2500, respectively, so no matter what you try it will always look wrong unless you load this file as an XML file and also check what the "viewbox" attribute reports as render dimensions, then using those, instead of the shape's .width and .height properties.

So your approach is correct! The SVG file is just an unfortunate test image.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I did notice later that there was a discrepancy between the measures in the SVG file. Still, there was no changing I could do there that allowed Processing to render the image correctly. But I could do it in Illustrator or in any other program. I'm still trying to get a way to do it.

Comment: that's because Illustrator and Inkscape etc. are design programs. They're not allowed to "hide" anything, they show you whole thing, though sometimes with the viewbox overlayed to show the clipping mask. Processing just loads it as if it's an image, instead. The simplest solution is to just grab the SVG file, and set height and width to the values from the viewbox instead. That should make it load just fine.

Comment: Well, I was looking more closely at this SVG file and it's got many errors. Still, no matter what you modify, it's impossible for Processing to read it. My approach was to open it in Inkscape and save it in plain SVG. After that Processing can read it **if** you change the viewport values of the file.